# Unable to simplify tensor expressions with xAct

Tags: xact

Using xAct package in Mathematica, I am trying to obtain expansions of Ricci scalar upto second order in metric perturbations. Although I am able to obtain the  perturbed expressions, Mathematica/xAct does not seem to simplify some tensor expressions. For example, there are terms like:

```
    p2[a, -a] p2[b, -b] - (p2[a, -a])^2
```

where `p2[a,b]` is a second rank tensor. I would like such expressions to be automatically simplified; in the above case, expected result is `0`. However, when I use the command `//Simplification`, I get the same expression. For instance, this is what I get for the above expression:

```
    In[42]:= p2[a, -a] * p2[b, -b] - (p2[a, -a])^2 // Simplification

    Out[42]= p2[a, -a]   p2[b, -b] - xAct`xTensor`Scalar[p2[a, -a]]^2
```

Why is xAct/Mathematica not recognizing the two terms as equal?

What is `xAct`xTensor`Scalar[]` object?

A prescription to simplify such expressions in general would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the xact notation, but are you sure the first term is contracted and the second one is not implicitly multiplyied by the identity tensor. So it could be a non zero tensor of second order.

Comment: Welcome! To make the most of Mma.SE start by **taking the [tour] now**. It will **help us to help you** if you write an [excellent question](https://goo.gl/BqKxV3). [Edit](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX) your question each time you find it can be improved to show due diligence, give more context. As you receive **give back**, vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Comment: @Gluoncito I am not an expert in xAct, but from what I understand it does take care of contractions of repeated indices. Using the command `//ScalarQ` returns `True` , implying that this expression is a scalar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An expression like `p[a, -a]^2` is strictly incorrect in xTensor, because in WL this is `p[a, -a]*p[a, -a]`, which has repeated indices. The way to avoid this problem is to hide internal scalar indices inside the `Scalar` head. That is, the expression `Scalar[p[a, -a]]^2` is the correct way to express that object in xTensor.

Your `Simplification` call finds an improper expression and tries to fix it by returning an unambiguous expression (this doesn't always work, because ambiguous input may be incorrectly interpreted sometimes). Use then the command `NoScalar`, which will rename indices to avoid collisions, and finally use `Simplification` or `ToCanonical` again. You'll get the expected zero output.

Alternative, the command `PutScalar` (internally used by `Simplification`) adds the `Scalar` heads, and then you can call `Simplification`:

```
In[7]:= p[a, -a] p[b, -b] - p[a, -a]^2 // PutScalar // Simplification
Out[7]= 0
```